Firebase firestore method causing incorrect values in database
This is how I run addPhoneNumber method
 if (await canCheckIn() && mounted) {
                      _checkIn();
    }
    
    
    Future<void> _checkIn() async { //canCheckIn is a firestore method
        await addPhoneNumber(Manager.phoneNumber); //firestore method
        getPhoneNumberCount(); //firestore method
        resetProgressBar();
    }

Future addPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) async {
_loadingDialog("Checking In...");
    final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final List<String> documentNames = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3', 'list4', 'list5'];
    const int maxNumbersPerDoc = 80000;  // Limit

    try {
      for (String docName in documentNames) {
        DocumentReference docRef = _firestore.collection('contest').doc(docName);

        // Read the document
        DocumentSnapshot docSnap = await docRef.get();
        Map<String, dynamic>? data = docSnap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?;
        List<dynamic> numbers = data?['numbers'] ?? [];

        // Check if the document has reached the limit
        if (numbers.length < maxNumbersPerDoc) {
          numbers.add(phoneNumber);

          // Update the document with the new phone number
          await docRef.update({'numbers': numbers});


          if (context.mounted) {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          }
          _vibrateAndPlaySound();
          _showDialog();
          _showInterstitialAd();
          loadCheckIns();

          return;  // Exit the method after successfully adding the number
        }
      }

      // If all documents are full, throw an exception
      throw Exception('All documents are full.');
    } catch (e) {
      toast_msg('Error adding phone number: $e');
      // Optionally handle the error in a different way, such as updating UI state
      // or logging the error for further analysis.
    }
  }

I am using this method in my flutter app to add phone numbers into an array called numbers. I have 5 documents each contains an array. I am assuming each document fits 80,000 strings in the array (8 digit strings) so I created 5 docs to avoid having problems in storing data in case of large traffic. If one is full the method uses the next one. My app is a giveway app where people are allowed to addPhoneNumber 3 times. After I checked the numbers array in firestore console I found some users phone repeated 9 times. Do you think race conditions or concurrency problem is happening with my method when many people are running it at the same time ? ChatGPT suggested using transactions. Your help will be appreciated in pointing out the cause.
Could this
await docRef.update({'numbers': numbers}); 

with the method being executed by around 50 people at a time, cause incorrect array values (duplicates, more items, less items) since all are updating the array at once ? Cause I faced such issue with incorrect values for an integer field I was incrementing by several users at a time, it lead to additional increments. I guess the same is happening here, what can I do to achieve more stable results in firestore updates , transactions is a solution ?
Other methods
     Future<bool> canCheckIn() async {
    _loadingDialog("Validating");
    if (Manager.userId != null) {
      final DocumentSnapshot userSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(Manager.userId)
          .get();

      if (userSnapshot.exists) {
        final userData = userSnapshot.data()
        as Map<String, dynamic>?; // Casting to Map<String, dynamic>

        if (userData != null && userData.containsKey('checkins')) {
          int checkins = userData['checkins'] ??
              0; // Default to 0 if checkins field is null

          if (checkins == 0) {
            if (mounted) {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }
            return false;
          } else {
            checkins--;
            local_checkin--;
            await userSnapshot.reference.update({'checkins': checkins});
            if (mounted) {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (mounted) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
    return false;
  }


Future<void> getPhoneNumberCount() async {
    final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final List<String> documentNames = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3', 'list4', 'list5'];
    const int maxNumbersPerDoc = 80000;  // Limit

    int totalCount = 0;

    try {
      for (String docName in documentNames) {
        DocumentReference docRef = _firestore.collection('contest').doc(docName);

        // Read the document snapshot
        DocumentSnapshot docSnap = await docRef.get();
        Map<String, dynamic>? data = docSnap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?;
        List<dynamic> numbers = data?['numbers'] ?? [];

        // Add the count of phone numbers to the total count
        totalCount += numbers.length;

        // Break the loop if the document is not full
        if (numbers.length < maxNumbersPerDoc) {
          break;
        }
      }

      // Update the state with the total count
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          userCount = totalCount; // Update the userCount state variable
        });
      }

    } catch (e) {
      print('Error retrieving phone number count: $e');
      // Handle error as needed
    }
  }


As far as I can see, you have no code that checks to see if there are any duplicate numbers before appending to the first list with space available, so it's not surprising that there might end up being duplicates.  There is no "race" required for this to happen, just repetition.

@DougStevenson i already allow up to 3 duplicate values. Cause i have a limit on how many times a user can enter the draw (addphoneNumber). Either firebase is acting up or my code is not accurate in adding values to the db.

Where is your code to allow only 3 duplicates?  As I said, I can see no code at all that restricts duplicates at all, so it's not surprising to me that you're observing any number of duplicates.  Your code allows any phone number to be appended to the array as long as there is room.

@DougStevenson i have a condition before executing this method if(limit < 3)

Without seeing that code, we don't know if that's actually the problem here.  There needs to be enough code in your post so that anyone can copy it and reproduce the issue.  What you're showing now just isn't complete and doesn't use any constraints on duplicate numbers.  You can definitely expect to see duplicates.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

@AlexMamo I updated the code, what Doug asked for is just an if statement i am sure it is not the cause. Please recheck my question I added clarification, I think you can figure it out as a firebase expert.

Please edit your question and add the code as requested.

@AlexMamo Done, code added

@DougStevenson Code updated check if you can point out the probable issue.

Still, none of the code you're showing here attempts to limit the number of distinct phone numbers to 3.

I give users 3 checkins per day thats it. My problem is sometimes the array misses some items out of nowhere, sometimes a lot of items duplicate, in a single operation as if its a lag. I am just asking if these type of problem appear in the way i add data to the firestore db, I just want a firebase expert to check the addphoneNumber method if it causes problems on high traffic when a lot of people are updating the array if u see my method updates the array locally and replaces the told one in firestore.
